# Search for text in mongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this kind of data in my mongoDB

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a26d554677475818a795f75"),
        "facebookId" : "123456",
        "gender" : "Female",
        "profileUrl" : "https://www.facebook.com/asdfasf",
        "imageUrl" : "/img/profile/sm1.jpg",
        "firstName" : "Anna",
        "token" : "ldhajksdkjasdakjsdajksd",
        "email" : "sm1@gmail.com"
    }
```

here let say i do a query

```
User.find({firstName:'Anna'},function(err, data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

It gives me her result
but I do `firstName:'nna'` or `firstName:'Ana'` or `firstName:'anna'` or any other combination. 
So how I can get the closest value for STRING in MongoDB using Mongoose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter results by whether they match a regular expression using the `$regex` operator.

Example:

```
const queryString = "an";
User.find(
  { firstName: { $regex: `^${queryString}.*`, $options: "i" } },
  (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

This will match all records whose `firstName` field starts with `an` (case-insensitive). You can build more complicated regular expressions to match your business requirements.

You can read more about the `$regex` operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

Comment: what about nna and aNa pls help @Veeram

Comment: You should write the regular expression yourself so that it matches your use-case.